# Mysql import large SQL file coming from SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I don't manage to success an importation into MySQL using mysql in command lines and I'm on Windows using XAMPP.

I have Googled and searched on stackoverflow for solutions but none are working. I've edited php.ini and my.ini with higher limits on:

- max_allowed_packet = 64M
- wait_timeout = 6000
- max_allowed_packet = 64M

Currently I have a 450Mb size .sql file and when I try importing it in mysql using command lines.

> mysql.exe -u root mcs < mcs.sql 
> Error: ASCII '\0' appeared in the
>   statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is
>   enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode.

I try again with this command :

> mysql.exe -u root --binary-mode mcs < mcs.sql 
>   ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1: MySQL server has gone away.

**UPDATE**

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and it seems I can build SQL file into ANSI or UCS-2 (I don't know what is the best to choose).

I've builded one .sql file just with a single table it has a size of 3Mb and keep crashing while importing because of bad syntax.

Here are few lines of my 3Mb .sql file (ANSI):

```
USE [mcs]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inventory](
    [item] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [descr] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [daymin] [money] NULL,
    [days_min] [smallint] NULL,
    [weekchg] [money] NULL,
    [monthchg] [money] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]  


GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[inventory] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[inventory] ([item], [descr], [daymin], [days_min], [weekchg], [monthchg]) VALUES (N'AGRAF8MM', 8mm Arrow', 11.8500, 0, 0.0000, 0.0000)
```

Comment: There might be a clue in MySQL's error log.

Comment: What character encoding is the .sql file?  Is it UTF-16 or UCS-2?

Comment: How did you create this file? What do the first few lines look like?

Comment: @BaconBits I don't know i think it should be UTF-8 or UTF-16 but I haven't found how to know it.

Comment: You can get a good guess what the encoding is by opening the file with a text editor that can tell you.  Notepad++ shows the current encoding at the bottom of the window, for example.  It will show ANSI, UTF-8, or UCS-2 (which is UTF-16, more or less).

Comment: @BaconBits Ah thanks! I can build the SQL file into ANSI or UCS-2 it seems from the SQL Server Management and what ever I choose the importation crash because of bad syntax. There is probably a parameters to set into the mysql command or into the SQL Server Management

Comment: @MattGibson SQL Server Management Studio for build the SQL file and i've updated my question for show few lines

Comment: Woah. You're trying to import a SQL Server script into MySQL? Those really won't be very compatible. As they have quite different syntax in many areas, it's unsurprising that you're getting syntax errors.

Comment: @MattGibson Oh ok. It's the first time I try to archive that. Do you know how to make it works? Source is MSSQL and destination would be MySQL

Comment: I don't know; migrating a database from one RDBMS to another is a complicated process--often there are many differences including available features, non-standard syntax, etc. etc. so this is quite a broad question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't a ascii text file. It's maybe gziped. 
What is the output if you type this in your cli? It should be `dumpfile.sql: ASCII text`

```
> file dumpfile.sql
```

If it's not ASCII text try to unzip it.

**Edit** Damn you are on windows. Try to find it out via gui.

Comment: I've find the ASCII parameter it was unicode by default. I changed to ASCII and did a new .sql file. I try importing again and come back for news